# How do I read data sandwiched between a certain character (Python 3.3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Okay, technically I have been assigned a task to complete and it involves loops (while, for, etc.) and I have come across a problem:

I was asked to store the scores and username, level etc. in a list format like this:

```
# <username>, <level>, <level_score> - Like this: 
['buzzysin,5,100','apple_maple,3,60','choco_charlie,2,25','buzzysin,1,10']
```

What I need to do is create a scoreboard using this data, but I cannot seem to isolate the scores from the string in the list. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
def scoreboard():
    name = input("Enter a username: ") # Say 'buzzysin'
    t = open('scores.txt', 'r')
    a = t.readlines()
    b = [] 
    t.close()
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if name not in a[i]:
            pass
        else: # Here I need to get the occurences of 'buzzysin' and append it to b
            b.append(a[i])
    #Then I need to extract the level and scores, but here's where I'm stuck :-(
```

My scoreboard need to look like this:

```
>>> scoreboard()
Please enter a name: buzzysin
The scores for buzzysin are:

    Level    Scores
-----------------------
      1        10
      2         0
      3         0
      4         0
      5       100

>>>
```

Please help,

`'buzzysin'`

Comment: I don't see how you get the scoreboard numbers from that data line you showed above. Please explain.

Comment: Just to say, the activity said to use the highest value for each level, so since there were no scores for Levels 2 - 4, they had to be replaced with a  0.

Comment: There's a score for level 3 and one for level 2.

Comment: But not for 'buzzysin'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `for i in len(a)` will raise an exception, since integers are not iterable. You either should directly iterate `a` or iterate a list of indices like `range(len(a))`. Secondly, if lines in `a` are formatted as follows `buzzysin,5,100` you should use the `string.startswith` intead of `in` (saves a hell lot of time). And then, if a string starts with  buzzysin, you can parse that string with `string.split(',')` to get the score. For instance,

```
for line in a:
    if line.startswith(player_name):
        name, level, score = line.rstrip().split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.split(',')`:

```
lines = ['buzzysin,5,100','apple_maple,3,60','choco_charlie,2,25','buzzysin,1,10']
for line in lines:
    name, level, score = line.split(',')
    print(name, 'is in level', level, 'with score', score)
```

Prints:

```
buzzysin is in level 5 with score 100
apple_maple is in level 3 with score 60
choco_charlie is in level 2 with score 25
buzzysin is in level 1 with score 10
```

Comment: That's not the format I need, but the `line.split(',')` seems to be what I need.

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to demonstrate that the split works. I usually just answer the question, not write a complete solution and force it on people :-)

Answer (score 0):

Go modular! Write a separate function for parsing each line, use it to parse all of the lines, and then filter out the scores for the relevant person. List comprehensions are great for this:

```
def parse_line(line):
    """parse a score line, returning its data

    A score line is of the form: <username>,<level>,<level_score>

    The level and score are integers.
    """
    parts = line.split(',')
    if len(parts) != 3:
        return None # or raise an exception
    name = parts[0]
    level = int(parts[1])
    level_score = int(parts[2])
    return name, level, level_score

# read the lines
with open('scores.txt', 'r') as t:
    lines = t.readlines()

# parse the lines, ignoring empty lines
scores = [parse_line(line) for line in lines if line != ""]

# get the person's name
name = input("Enter a username: ") # Say 'buzzysin'

# filter that person's scores
persons_scores = [score for score in scores if score[0] == name]

# now print your table...
```

Comment: Sorry - I am not sure if I understand... I am a SUPER newbie at Python. Could you explain?

Also I should have mentioned this earlier, but if there are multiple occurrences of two different scores in the same level:

    ['buzzysin,2,30','buzzysin,2,45']

I am meant to show the highest of the two -> 'buzzysin,2,45'

Comment: Which parts are not clear? Here are short introductions about [list comprehensions](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) and the [with statement](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/).

Comment: As for choosing the highest score for each level, that's a different question altogether. You're welcome to open a separate question about it.

Comment: `scores = [parse_line(line) for line in lines if line != ""]` - it's sufficient (and proper) to write `...if line]`

Comment: @EliKorvigo Indeed, that would be sufficient, but the person asking the question is a Python newbie so I preferred clarity over brevity and elegance.

Answer (score 0):

```
# get all scoreboard data
data = ['buzzysin,5,100','apple_maple,3,60','choco_charlie,2,25','buzzysin,1,10']
# get target name
target_name = input("Enter a username: ")
# initialize our target scoreboard
target_scoreboard = {}
# get scoreboard data for our target
for name_data in data: # look at all the data, one item at a time
    if name_data.split(',')[0] == target_name:
        # if this data is for our target, add it to out target scoreboard
        level = int(name_data.split(',')[1])
        score = int(name_data.split(',')[2])
        target_scoreboard[level] = score

# print scoreboard for our target, sorted by level
print("\tLevel\tScore")
print("-"*25)
for level in sorted(target_scoreboard):
    print('\t{:d}\t{:d}'.format(level, target_scoreboard[level]))
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I am really new to python - could you put comments showing what each major part does?

Thanks